# ASP/VB Selection issue with radioboxes

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

so I have what I hope is a simple problem.

I have a dynamic radio select on my site which pulls from a SQL database the code for this is below:

```
Dim thisvisa As Integer = 0
        Dim n = 1
        For n = 1 To 10
If AccountReader(thisvisaprice) > 0 Then
                    rbprocessingfees.Items.Insert(thisvisa, New ListItem(AccountReader(thisvisastr) & "&nbsp;&nbsp; £" & AccountReader(thisvisaprice), AccountReader(thisvisaprice)))
                Else
                    rbprocessingfees.Items.Insert(thisvisa, New ListItem(AccountReader(thisvisastr), AccountReader(thisvisastr)))
                End If

                thisvisa = thisvisa + 1
```

now heres where I am stuck.

say for example the user clicks the 2nd option down I need it to set a page variable to something to say essentially the 2nd option down is set. I need this to be for example

```
Context.Session("VisaSwift_setoption") = option2
```

this is so that I can pull an additional field from the SQL database to tie up with this and increase a charge.

as the above is dynamic and can have any number of options (up to 10)  I cant set all the variables initially?

I am scratching my head here, please help!

thanks,

Arran

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event to your RadioButtonList and set the `AutoPostBack` to `true`. You can then get the selected value into a Session.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbprocessingfees" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rbprocessingfees_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Code behind

```
Protected Sub rbprocessingfees_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Session("VisaSwift_setoption") = rbprocessingfees.SelectedValue
End Sub
```